# Failed attempt at moving Drupal 8 to a clean installation of my OS.

Tags: 8, .htaccess, uri

Okay, so ive reinstalled my ubuntu OS,  reinstalled the LAMP stack, ive restored the database and connected to it just fine. Ive checked which php modules drupal 8 requires and installed them, my version of php is above the 5.6 lower limit - i have not installed ALL of the php5-* modules in apt-cache though but i dont think thats an issue(?), ive set the chmod 777 . But now my /user/login kind of routes dont work, it just gives a 404. Have anyone experience anything like this, and how to solve?

I have looked at the clean_urls in my .htaccess, but drupal 8 clean urls should just work out of the box.

Comment: I would advise using a VM to sidestep all of this setup, there are lots out there ready to go for Drupal that are configured appropriately.

Comment: Well Ive fixed it now, i dont think its too much of hazzle to set up dev for drupal  in general and i really do prefer not using vm's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i went inside of /etc/apache2.conf and changed

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

that worked :)

Comment: Life Saver! I migrated Drupal from windows to Ubuntu and had the same issue. This solved it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether you have activated the `mod_rewrite` Apache module? According to the [INSTALL.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!INSTALL.txt/8) file for Drupal 8,

> If you want to use Drupal's "Clean URLs" feature on an Apache web
>   server, you   will need the mod_rewrite module and the ability to use
>   local .htaccess   files.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled when i run phpinfo(), and  i just found out that the clean urls actually work, as in: mydrupal/index.php/user/login ... so i have a feeling its something about the document root, im not really an expert on that area to say the least though.